# Loading a 8.9 GB dataset from Google Drive to Google Colab?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am working on a huge laboratory dataset and want to know how to load an 8.9GB dataset from my google drive to my google colab file. The error it shows is runtime stopped, Restarting it.

I've already tried chunksize, nrows, na_filter, and dask. There might be a problem implementing them though. If you could explain to me how to use it. I am attaching my original code below.

```
import pandas as pd

!pip install -U -q PyDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

id = '1M4tregypJ_HpXaQCIykyG2lQtAMR9nPe'
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':id}) 
downloaded.GetContentFile('Filename.csv')  
df = pd.read_csv('Filename.csv')

df.head()
```

If you suggest any of the methods I've already tried please do so with appropriate and working code.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: Have you tried using [mounting your Drive as a filesystem](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA)? You'll also likely have a much simpler time if you split things into multiple files rather than working with a single 8.9G file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably from `pd.read_csv('Filename.csv')`.

A 8.9GB CSV file will take more than 13GB RAM. You should not load the whole file into memory, but work incrementally.